# How to constraint a route with a specific role in my case with vue-auth?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I develop my first Laravel application with Vue-js in SPA.

I try to forbid access to a route (view-router) through a role.

For roles, I use the  spatie/laravel-permission package.

I set up view-auth `rolesVar` like this:

```
const config = {
   rolesVar: 'roles',
   …
}
```

Here is an example of a user in json

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "data":{
      "id":1,
      "first_name":"John",
      "last_name":"Doe",
      "email":"john@Doe",
      "created_at":"2019-07-11 11:20:20",
      "updated_at":"2019-07-11 11:20:20",
      "all_permissions":[

      ],
      "can":[

      ],
      "permissions":[

      ],
      "roles":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"super-admin",
            "guard_name":"api",
            "created_at":"2019-07-11 11:20:20",
            "updated_at":"2019-07-11 11:20:20",
            "pivot":{
               "model_id":1,
               "role_id":1,
               "model_type":"App\\Models\\User"
            },
            "permissions":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I try to force my role like this, but it does not work. I am redirected to / 403 (as requested).

I conclude that he does not take my role.

```
{
path: '/admin',
name: 'admin.dashboard',
component: AdminDashboard,
meta: {
  auth: {
    roles: { name: 'super-admin' },
    redirect: { name: 'login' },
    forbiddenRedirect: { path: '/403' }
  }
}
```

},

I think it's because I have several json objects in "roles" but I don't know what to call it for it to work

Thanks for your help !

Comment: its better it you implement security at server side, client side JS is easier to trick

Comment: @SerakShiferaw, yes of course, There is server-side security but I also need client-side security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use server side security instead of client side like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission:permission1|permission2']], function () {
    Route::get('/protected_URL',function(){
        return "I can only access this if i only have permission1 and permission2";
    });
});
```

this was only authenticated user and user having "permission1" and "permission2" have access to this page, otherwise it will thought access denied error where you can easily catch this error with axios and display Access Denied message

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is a SPA application (single-page-application). Laravel only handles API routes. It is view-router that manages the pages routes.